# jQuery Fancy Tree with Local Array Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, treeview

I am trying to implement jQuery FancyTree http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/ with local array data

Referred from https://code.google.com/p/fancytree/

**This is the code. But it is not working, No Script Error.But Tree is empty!!!**

> Even i copied the jQuery, UI versions of the file they using in a demo
>   site. Still nothing works

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tree").fancytree({
                onActivate: function (node) {
                    // A DynaTreeNode object is passed to the activation handler

                    // Note: we also get this event, if persistence is on, and the 
                     //  age is reloaded.
                    alert("You activated " + node.data.title);
                },

                children: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                {title: "Item 1" },
                { title: "Folder 2", isFolder: true,
                    children: [
                        { title: "Sub-item 2.1" },
                        { title: "Sub-item 2.2" }
                    ]
                },
                { title: "Item 3" }
            ]
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed that `source:[]` is how you initializes the tree in `$("#tabTree").fancytree()` initialization call, so your example would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#tree").fancytree({
                onActivate: function (node) {
                    // A DynaTreeNode object is passed to the activation handler

                    // Note: we also get this event, if persistence is on, and the 
                     //  age is reloaded.
                    alert("You activated " + node.data.title);
                },
                source: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                {title: "Item 1" },
                { title: "Folder 2", isFolder: true,
                    children: [
                        { title: "Sub-item 2.1" },
                        { title: "Sub-item 2.2" }
                    ]
                },
                { title: "Item 3" }
            ]
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

btw, in case you noticed it, the documentation is quite messy, as they are refactoring the code, the documentation is half what's left from dynatree and the new conventions of fancytree. So expect more weird stuff like that :-)

Comment: You are correct. But with fancy tree i could not call render method in each children node, as it is used in dyna tree. It says parent.ul is null :(

Comment: I was talking this.   var childNodes = node.getChildren();

            if (childNodes != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
                    var alreadySelected = childNodes[i].data.select;
                    if (!alreadySelected) {
                        childNodes[i].data.icon = "star_silver.png";
                        childNodes[i].render(false, false);
                        
                    }
                }
            }

Answer (score -1):

are the Scriptpath right?

Do you download "jquery.js, jquery-ui.custom.js, ui.fancytree.css and jquery.fancytree.js" ?

Comment: Yes. Thats wat i mentioned in question. Do i need to rename Copied to Downloaded?